# Trying to send url in json body as value in JMETER but getting json parse error

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to fire a post with body as below but getting json parse error. I understand it is because of the url that i am trying to pass. can this be resolved.

[image: Jmeter Body]

My Body:

```
{"type":"transformation","tags":[],"properties":"{\"expressionList\":[{\"id\":1,\"outputColumn\":\"formout\",\"filterExpression\":\"{\\"fields\\":[{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"ifelsestructure\\"},\\"displayString\\":\\"If\\",\\"label\\":\\"If\\",\\"id\\":\\"If\\",\\"value\\":\\"If\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"operator\\"},\\"displayString\\":\\"(\\",\\"id\\":\\"(\\",\\"label\\":\\"(\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"external_api_object\\",\\"url\\":\\"http://simbox-predictor-default-00001-private.staging.svc.cluster.local/v1/models/simbox\\"},\\"id\\":1,\\"displayString\\":\\"simbox\\",\\"label\\":\\"simbox\\",\\"value\\":\\"simbox\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"external_api_function\\",\\"url\\":\\"http://simbox-predictor-default-00001-private.staging.svc.cluster.local/v1/models/simbox\\",\\"externalApiInputData\\":{\\"controls\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"ncalls\\",\\"label\\":\\"ncalls\\",\\"value\\":\\"ncalls\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_caller\\",\\"label\\":\\"nd_caller\\",\\"value\\":\\"nd_caller\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_called\\",\\"label\\":\\"nd_called\\",\\"value\\":\\"nd_called\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"incoming\\",\\"label\\":\\"incoming\\",\\"value\\":\\"incoming\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"outgoing\\",\\"label\\":\\"outgoing\\",\\"value\\":\\"outgoing\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"sumduration\\",\\"label\\":\\"sumduration\\",\\"value\\":\\"sumduration\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"sumincomingduration\\",\\"label\\":\\"sumincomingduration\\",\\"value\\":\\"sumincomingduration\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"ndimei\\",\\"label\\":\\"ndimei\\",\\"value\\":\\"ndimei\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"ndimeitac\\",\\"label\\":\\"ndimeitac\\",\\"value\\":\\"ndimeitac\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_geopos\\",\\"label\\":\\"nd_geopos\\",\\"value\\":\\"nd_geopos\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_lac\\",\\"label\\":\\"nd_lac\\",\\"value\\":\\"nd_lac\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"ndotherpartynumber\\",\\"label\\":\\"ndotherpartynumber\\",\\"value\\":\\"ndotherpartynumber\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"onnet_outgoing_count\\",\\"label\\":\\"onnet_outgoing_count\\",\\"value\\":\\"onnet_outgoing_count\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"ext_duration_count\\",\\"label\\":\\"ext_duration_count\\",\\"value\\":\\"ext_duration_count\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"office_hr_calls\\",\\"label\\":\\"office_hr_calls\\",\\"value\\":\\"office_hr_calls\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"avgusageincoming\\",\\"label\\":\\"avgusageincoming\\",\\"value\\":\\"avgusageincoming\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"on_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"on_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"on_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"nd_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"nd_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"outgoing_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"outgoing_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"outgoing_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"in_duration_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"in_duration_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"in_duration_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"calls_ndcalled\\",\\"label\\":\\"calls_ndcalled\\",\\"value\\":\\"calls_ndcalled\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"ext_duration_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"ext_duration_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"ext_duration_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"calls_geo_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"calls_geo_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"calls_geo_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"ab_overlap_out\\",\\"label\\":\\"ab_overlap_out\\",\\"value\\":\\"ab_overlap_out\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"office_hr_calls_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"office_hr_calls_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"office_hr_calls_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio\\",\\"label\\":\\"nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio\\",\\"value\\":\\"nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\",\\"required\\":true,\\"validators\\":{\\"required\\":true}}]},\\"selectOptions\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"ncalls\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_caller\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_called\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"incoming\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"outgoing\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"sumduration\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"sumincomingduration\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"ndimei\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"ndimeitac\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_geopos\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_lac\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"ndotherpartynumber\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"onnet_outgoing_count\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"ext_duration_count\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"office_hr_calls\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"avgusageincoming\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"on_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"outgoing_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"in_duration_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"calls_ndcalled\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"ext_duration_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"calls_geo_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"ab_overlap_out\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"office_hr_calls_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"test_integer\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"test_float\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"}],\\"outputOptions\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"instance_id\\",\\"type\\":\\"string\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"prediction\\",\\"type\\":\\"integer\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"probability_0\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"},{\\"name\\":\\"probability_1\\",\\"type\\":\\"float\\"}]},\\"id\\":\\"simbox\\",\\"label\\":\\"simbox\\",\\"displayString\\":\\"simbox\\",\\"value\\":\\"simbox\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"inputParameters\\":[\\"ncalls\\",\\"nd_caller\\",\\"nd_called\\",\\"incoming\\",\\"outgoing\\",\\"sumduration\\",\\"sumincomingduration\\",\\"ndimei\\",\\"ndimeitac\\",\\"nd_geopos\\",\\"nd_lac\\",\\"ndotherpartynumber\\",\\"onnet_outgoing_count\\",\\"ext_duration_count\\",\\"office_hr_calls\\",\\"avgusageincoming\\",\\"on_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"nd_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"outgoing_ratio\\",\\"in_duration_ratio\\",\\"calls_ndcalled\\",\\"ext_duration_ratio\\",\\"calls_geo_ratio\\",\\"ab_overlap_out\\",\\"office_hr_calls_ratio\\",\\"nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio\\",\\"nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio\\"],\\"inputParameterNames\\":[\\"ncalls\\",\\"nd_caller\\",\\"nd_called\\",\\"incoming\\",\\"outgoing\\",\\"sumduration\\",\\"sumincomingduration\\",\\"ndimei\\",\\"ndimeitac\\",\\"nd_geopos\\",\\"nd_lac\\",\\"ndotherpartynumber\\",\\"onnet_outgoing_count\\",\\"ext_duration_count\\",\\"office_hr_calls\\",\\"avgusageincoming\\",\\"on_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"nd_outgoing_ratio\\",\\"outgoing_ratio\\",\\"in_duration_ratio\\",\\"calls_ndcalled\\",\\"ext_duration_ratio\\",\\"calls_geo_ratio\\",\\"ab_overlap_out\\",\\"office_hr_calls_ratio\\",\\"nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio\\",\\"nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio\\"],\\"outputParameter\\":\\"prediction\\",\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"external_api_function_parameter\\",\\"dataType\\":\\"integer\\"},\\"name\\":\\"(ncalls, nd_caller, nd_called, incoming, outgoing, sumduration, sumincomingduration, ndimei, ndimeitac, nd_geopos, nd_lac, ndotherpartynumber, onnet_outgoing_count, ext_duration_count, office_hr_calls, avgusageincoming, on_outgoing_ratio, nd_outgoing_ratio, outgoing_ratio, in_duration_ratio, calls_ndcalled, ext_duration_ratio, calls_geo_ratio, ab_overlap_out, office_hr_calls_ratio, nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio, nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio)::Output(prediction)\\",\\"label\\":\\"(ncalls, nd_caller, nd_called, incoming, outgoing, sumduration, sumincomingduration, ndimei, ndimeitac, nd_geopos, nd_lac, ndotherpartynumber, onnet_outgoing_count, ext_duration_count, office_hr_calls, avgusageincoming, on_outgoing_ratio, nd_outgoing_ratio, outgoing_ratio, in_duration_ratio, calls_ndcalled, ext_duration_ratio, calls_geo_ratio, ab_overlap_out, office_hr_calls_ratio, nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio, nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio)::Output(prediction)\\",\\"id\\":\\"(ncalls, nd_caller, nd_called, incoming, outgoing, sumduration, sumincomingduration, ndimei, ndimeitac, nd_geopos, nd_lac, ndotherpartynumber, onnet_outgoing_count, ext_duration_count, office_hr_calls, avgusageincoming, on_outgoing_ratio, nd_outgoing_ratio, outgoing_ratio, in_duration_ratio, calls_ndcalled, ext_duration_ratio, calls_geo_ratio, ab_overlap_out, office_hr_calls_ratio, nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio, nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio)::Output(prediction)\\",\\"displayString\\":\\"(ncalls, nd_caller, nd_called, incoming, outgoing, sumduration, sumincomingduration, ndimei, ndimeitac, nd_geopos, nd_lac, ndotherpartynumber, onnet_outgoing_count, ext_duration_count, office_hr_calls, avgusageincoming, on_outgoing_ratio, nd_outgoing_ratio, outgoing_ratio, in_duration_ratio, calls_ndcalled, ext_duration_ratio, calls_geo_ratio, ab_overlap_out, office_hr_calls_ratio, nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio, nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio)::Output(prediction)\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"operator\\"},\\"id\\":5,\\"displayString\\":\\">\\",\\"label\\":\\">\\",\\"value\\":\\">\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"constant\\",\\"dataType\\":\\"int\\",\\"regex\\":\\"[0-9] \\"},\\"name\\":\\"50\\",\\"displayString\\":\\"50\\",\\"label\\":\\"50\\",\\"id\\":\\"50\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"operator\\"},\\"displayString\\":\\")\\",\\"id\\":\\")\\",\\"label\\":\\")\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"ifelsestructure\\"},\\"displayString\\":\\"Then\\",\\"label\\":\\"Then\\",\\"id\\":\\"Then\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"operator\\"},\\"displayString\\":\\"(\\",\\"id\\":\\"(\\",\\"label\\":\\"(\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"data_record\\",\\"dataType\\":\\"float\\",\\"width\\":50},\\"id\\":30,\\"label\\":\\"test_float\\",\\"displayString\\":\\"test_float\\",\\"name\\":\\"test_float\\",\\"value\\":\\"test_float\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"},{\\"attribute\\":{\\"fieldIndicator\\":\\"operator\\"},\\"displayString\\":\\")\\",\\"id\\":\\")\\",\\"label\\":\\")\\",\\"noOfTabSpace\\":\\"0\\",\\"isEnteredSpace\\":\\"0\\"}]}\",\"dataType\":{\"display\":\"String\",\"type\":\"string\",\"format\":null}}]}","name":"jmeterFORM003","subType":"data-transform-formula-operator","inputSchema":"[{\"id\":11060,\"name\":\"aiml_testing_summarizer\",\"recordStructures\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"ncalls\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"nd_caller\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"nd_called\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"incoming\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"outgoing\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"sumduration\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"sumincomingduration\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"ndimei\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"ndimeitac\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"nd_geopos\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"nd_lac\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"ndotherpartynumber\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"onnet_outgoing_count\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"ext_duration_count\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"office_hr_calls\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":16,\"name\":\"avgusageincoming\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":17,\"name\":\"on_outgoing_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":18,\"name\":\"nd_outgoing_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":19,\"name\":\"outgoing_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"in_duration_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":21,\"name\":\"calls_ndcalled\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":22,\"name\":\"ext_duration_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":23,\"name\":\"calls_geo_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":24,\"name\":\"ab_overlap_out\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":25,\"name\":\"office_hr_calls_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":26,\"name\":\"nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":27,\"name\":\"nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":28,\"name\":\"test_integer\",\"dataType\":\"Integer\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"test_long\",\"dataType\":\"Long\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":30,\"name\":\"test_float\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":31,\"name\":\"test_double\",\"dataType\":\"Double\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":32,\"name\":\"test_string\",\"dataType\":\"String\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":33,\"name\":\"test_character\",\"dataType\":\"Char\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":34,\"name\":\"time_stamp\",\"dataType\":\"Timestamp\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null}]}]","outputSchema":"[{\"id\":11060,\"name\":\"formula\",\"recordStructures\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"ncalls\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"nd_caller\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"nd_called\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"incoming\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"outgoing\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"sumduration\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"sumincomingduration\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"ndimei\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"ndimeitac\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"nd_geopos\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"nd_lac\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"ndotherpartynumber\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"onnet_outgoing_count\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"ext_duration_count\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"office_hr_calls\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":16,\"name\":\"avgusageincoming\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":17,\"name\":\"on_outgoing_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":18,\"name\":\"nd_outgoing_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":19,\"name\":\"outgoing_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"in_duration_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":21,\"name\":\"calls_ndcalled\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":22,\"name\":\"ext_duration_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":23,\"name\":\"calls_geo_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":24,\"name\":\"ab_overlap_out\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":25,\"name\":\"office_hr_calls_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":26,\"name\":\"nd_outgoing_gre60_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":27,\"name\":\"nd_called_gre60_orig_ratio\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":28,\"name\":\"test_integer\",\"dataType\":\"Integer\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"test_long\",\"dataType\":\"Long\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":30,\"name\":\"test_float\",\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":31,\"name\":\"test_double\",\"dataType\":\"Double\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":32,\"name\":\"test_string\",\"dataType\":\"String\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":33,\"name\":\"test_character\",\"dataType\":\"Char\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":34,\"name\":\"time_stamp\",\"dataType\":\"Timestamp\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null},{\"id\":35,\"name\":\"formout\",\"mandatory\":false,\"format\":null,\"dataType\":\"string\"}]}]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2897748) as we cannot say whether your JSON is valid without seeing it fully, moreover I don't think anyone here is willing to type the whole payload into his text editor or use OCR tools for this.
2. Check that your JSON payload is valid using i.e. online JSON validator tools like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)
3. Just in case make sure to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema)
4. If you're trying to mimic the request from browser or desktop application you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and parameterize the URL later on if needed.

Comment: Hi @dmitri.. I have added the full json now in the post.

Comment: Also i have already validated using json validator, used content types as mentioned and my json is captured by recording.
Thanks a lot for your response. looking forword to your suggestions

Comment: The JSON you shared is not valid, I cannot suggest anything because I don't know how it's supposed to look like originally